# Errno description in a possibly multithreaded environment

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r

These functions are weird. Why can't I simply get a pointer to string literal (`const char*`) and be done with it?

Why mess around with a hidden static buffer that creates problems with threads and signals, or user-allocated buffers where you guess what a good size is because you don't know and the man page won't tell?

Anything I'm not getting?
What's wrong with a straightforward threads-are-irrelevant `strerror` implementation such as?:

```
#include <errno.h>
#define E(n,s) case n: return s;
const char* strerror(int n){
  switch(n){
    //stole these messages from libc
    E(EILSEQ,       "Illegal byte sequence")
    E(EDOM,         "Domain error")
    E(ERANGE,       "Result not representable")

    E(ENOTTY,       "Not a tty")
    E(EACCES,       "Permission denied")
    E(EPERM,        "Operation not permitted")
    E(ENOENT,       "No such file or directory")
    E(ESRCH,        "No such process")
    E(EEXIST,       "File exists")

    E(EOVERFLOW,    "Value too large for data type")
    E(ENOSPC,       "No space left on device")
    E(ENOMEM,       "Out of memory")

    E(EBUSY,        "Resource busy")
    E(EINTR,        "Interrupted system call")
    E(EAGAIN,       "Resource temporarily unavailable")
    E(ESPIPE,       "Invalid seek")

    E(EXDEV,        "Cross-device link")
    E(EROFS,        "Read-only file system")
    E(ENOTEMPTY,    "Directory not empty")

    E(ECONNRESET,   "Connection reset by peer")
    E(ETIMEDOUT,    "Operation timed out")
    E(ECONNREFUSED, "Connection refused")
    E(EHOSTDOWN,    "Host is down")
    E(EHOSTUNREACH, "Host is unreachable")
    E(EADDRINUSE,   "Address in use")

    E(EPIPE,        "Broken pipe")
    E(EIO,          "I/O error")
    E(ENXIO,        "No such device or address")
    E(ENOTBLK,      "Block device required")
    E(ENODEV,       "No such device")
    E(ENOTDIR,      "Not a directory")
    E(EISDIR,       "Is a directory")
    E(ETXTBSY,      "Text file busy")
    E(ENOEXEC,      "Exec format error")

    E(EINVAL,       "Invalid argument")

    E(E2BIG,        "Argument list too long")
    E(ELOOP,        "Symbolic link loop")
    E(ENAMETOOLONG, "Filename too long")
    E(ENFILE,       "Too many open files in system")
    E(EMFILE,       "No file descriptors available")
    E(EBADF,        "Bad file descriptor")
    E(ECHILD,       "No child process")
    E(EFAULT,       "Bad address")
    E(EFBIG,        "File too large")
    E(EMLINK,       "Too many links")
    E(ENOLCK,       "No locks available")

    E(EDEADLK,      "Resource deadlock would occur")
    E(ENOTRECOVERABLE, "State not recoverable")
    E(EOWNERDEAD,   "Previous owner died")
    E(ECANCELED,    "Operation canceled")
    E(ENOSYS,       "Function not implemented")
    E(ENOMSG,       "No message of desired type")
    E(EIDRM,        "Identifier removed")
    E(ENOSTR,       "Device not a stream")
    E(ENODATA,      "No data available")
    E(ETIME,        "Device timeout")
    E(ENOSR,        "Out of streams resources")
    E(ENOLINK,      "Link has been severed")
    E(EPROTO,       "Protocol error")
    E(EBADMSG,      "Bad message")
    E(EBADFD,       "File descriptor in bad state")
    E(ENOTSOCK,     "Not a socket")
    E(EDESTADDRREQ, "Destination address required")
    E(EMSGSIZE,     "Message too large")
    E(EPROTOTYPE,   "Protocol wrong type for socket")
    E(ENOPROTOOPT,  "Protocol not available")
    E(EPROTONOSUPPORT,"Protocol not supported")
    E(ESOCKTNOSUPPORT,"Socket type not supported")
    E(ENOTSUP,      "Not supported")
    E(EPFNOSUPPORT, "Protocol family not supported")
    E(EAFNOSUPPORT, "Address family not supported by protocol")
    E(EADDRNOTAVAIL,"Address not available")
    E(ENETDOWN,     "Network is down")
    E(ENETUNREACH,  "Network unreachable")
    E(ENETRESET,    "Connection reset by network")
    E(ECONNABORTED, "Connection aborted")
    E(ENOBUFS,      "No buffer space available")
    E(EISCONN,      "Socket is connected")
    E(ENOTCONN,     "Socket not connected")
    E(ESHUTDOWN,    "Cannot send after socket shutdown")
    E(EALREADY,     "Operation already in progress")
    E(EINPROGRESS,  "Operation in progress")
    E(ESTALE,       "Stale file handle")
    E(EREMOTEIO,    "Remote I/O error")
    E(EDQUOT,       "Quota exceeded")
    E(ENOMEDIUM,    "No medium found")
    E(EMEDIUMTYPE,  "Wrong medium type")
    E(0,            "No error information")
  }
  return "";
}
#undef E
```

Comment: Doesn't `strerror` do exactly what you want? They forgot the `const` and may overwrite the buffer, but other than that it looks ok.

Comment: @nwp The manpage says that the string "must not be modified by the application, but may be modified by a subsequent call to strerror()". That makes the standard `strerror` nonreentrant and the reentrancy is solved with `strerror_r`, which is clumsy because you have to guess a good buffer size. A simple switch with `const char*` strings doesn't have any of these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `strerror`  is correct. But the standard one from your C standard library might be locale aware (see [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html)) and that makes it non-reentant.

In practice, `errno` is today (usually) a macro expanded to some function call.

In my `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h` *internal* header there is:

```
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

and `strerror_r` exists to *fill* a buffer (which has to be thread specific) from some error number.

Comment: Section 7.5 of the C standard requires that `errno` be a macro:  *... `errno` which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type `int` and thread local storage duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions. If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into locales.

Comment: Looks like musl doesn't even use static buffers so its strerror should be trivially reentrant (and I don't see why it shouldn't--it shouldn't be a problem to look up a translation without always trying to make a global copy of it in one place). The glibc's strerror is not however. I'll stick with the custom version. I don't need translations anyway and this seems clearer than playing the strerror_r game. Thanks for the advice.